# Jquery + Rails - Drag & drop between two lists

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Background: I am upgrading an old Rails 2 application to Rails 3. This application has a feature where users can drag & drop elements between two lists. I tried to duplicate the functionality by using, Jquery demo:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/shopping-cart.html

I am able to show two lists and drag & drop between them. But I am not well versed with Jquery and don't know how to save data.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use this data you need to take a two steps:

- Take the list that is generated from jQuery and iterate through the names of the elements.
- Once you have built an array of the names you can send it to your controller action.

You are going to want to use better selectors however this code should point you in the right path.
Iterating through a list and creating an array is easy:

```
var g_cartItems = jQuery.makeArray(jQuery('#cart ol').children());
```

And then for submitting the data you could use something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "www.yoursite.com",
  data: g_cartItems,
  type: 'post'
});
```

Comment: This points me to right direction. I will post the complete code once I am done with it.